# What is this? (Something to do with water filtering?)

Tags: plumbing

I have the following thing in my basement and I'm not quite sure exactly what it is. I believe it has something to do with either hard water, or water filtration.

So my two questions would be:
1. What is it?
2. Can I get rid of it? (Or get a smaller version of it)?

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That appears to be the regeneration controller for a water softening system. You can't get rid of it because all water softener systems need to be periodically regenerated (which basically amounts to flushing the system with water to carry away the absorbed minerals) to allow them to continue working.

Comment: you'll also, at some point, need to replace the salt typically used

Comment: or just live with non-softened water

Comment: if it is a softener (as seems most likely - certainly the most common) there should also be a "brine tank" attached to one of the hoses that will need salt added to it from time to time. There are other types of filters that use timed regeneration which may not have the brine tank associated. Best bet is to take a sample of the water from before the filter and have it tested. While non-softeed water is an option, it can run up other expenses - someone I know won't put in a softener, but keeps having to replace their tankless coil, as it "muds up".

Comment: You can buy hardness test strips online, which is a pretty simple way to test the hardness before and after. However, since you appear to have a private system -- probably a well -- it is not a bad idea to have the water tested so you know what you're dealing with (eg if the water is safe to drink, use for cooking, showering, etc). The best way is to get a company that specializes in water treatment to come in and assess your system and take some samples for lab analysis. You may also be able to have bacteria testing done for free (in Ontario, the local health units provide this service).

Answer (score 5):

It is a Water Softener.  The clear hose on the right side that goes down should go to a brine tank.  The Brine tank should have water and salt in it.

There are instructions on the front of the panel for setting up the regen and triggering a manual regen cycle.

It is worth keeping the system.  Water Sofeners eliminate Calcium and Magnesium from your water.  Eliminating these elements will keep your plumbing fixtures such as shower heads from clogging up.  Appliances such as coffee makers will last longer as Calcium and magnesium typically builds up inside the system.  Soft water will result in better performance of your soap and detergents.

If you test your water and find out that the softener is not working don't give up on the system right away.  Typically if the system hasn't been regened and the resin is overrun - it can be brought back to a functioning level by doing back to back regen cycles.  You will want to wait 6 hours in between completion of a regen cycle before doing another one.  Back to back regen cycles will bring the resin back to life.  Every time the system does a regen cycle it will consume salt from the brine tank.